# Country code RD returned on ipinfodb v2

Tags: php, ip, country-codes

I'm using ipinfodb via PHP v2. ipinfodb returns 3-5% of our daily calls with CountryCode as 'RD'. Can't find RD in valid country codes. I will start logging IP's for RD returns, so far I only know that the majority of these users are on cell phone networks.

I'm using the following to call ipinfodb's API.

```
$sc=stream_context_create(array('http'=>array('timeout'=>5)));
$r=file_get_contents("http://api.ipinfodb.com/v2/ip_query_country.php?key=***",0,$sc);
$a=new SimpleXMLElement($r);
$country=$a->CountryCode;
```

Comment: See code, this question is for ipinfodb API v2, not API v3. 'RD' returns are not handled as in intended by ipinfodb for their v2 API. In all my logged cases v2 returned 'RD' for non-reserved IPs, while v3 returned accurate country codes. The correct solution maybe to simply use ipinfodb v3.

Answer (score 0):

→ I did some research and didn't find a straight-up definition for "**RD**" but did find this in someone's code on [*w3lessons*](http://www.w3lessons.com/2011/09/select-country-drop-down-based-on.html):

```
// Check if Local
if($country_code=="RD")
$country_code="US";
```

→ Hope that helps :p

Comment: Interesting. Will log a few IPs for 'RD' and check if they are indeed local.